Keithley 2290-5 testing setup power diode in reverse bias
I have to analyse the I-V characteristics in reverse of a power diode. So I would do a setup test to ground the diode safely. Which documents or paper could I read?
EDIT: I haven't the protection module and the GPIB

This is an intended application of the unit so read the Keithley manual carefully (including all the warnings) and seek local on-site assistance and guidance from someone familiar with dealing with 5kV power supplies during the process and definitely before applying power. If no such person is available, refuse the work.
The datasheet recommends the use of a  2290-PM-200 SMU Protection Module for testing reverse breakdown of high-voltage diodes.  There are diagrams showing properly interlocked enclosures for testing diodes.
From what I can see the unit is a unipolar power supply that supplies a positive voltage relative to chassis ground. The power supply must be properly grounded for safety.
But 5kV at several mA is dangerous regardless of grounding, hence interlocks and protection for any circuitry that is connected to the HV.

Thank you for your answer. I haven't the protection module and the GPIB neither, I should bypass interlock, so I think that I cannot do it.
